# Expression does not evaluate to a constant

Tags: c++

I've just started to learn C++ and I don't understand this error:

```
std::string AFunction(const std::string& str) {
    size_t s = str.length();

    char inProgress[s];


    return std::string();
}
```

I get the error:

> error C2131: expression does not evaluate to a constant

Here: `char inProgress[s];`

What do I have to do the set `inProgress` size with the length of `str`?

Comment: Variable sized arrays are not standard C++. You may be able to use [`alloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-170), but I am unsure if msvc supports that. Otherwise only dynamic allocation can solve your problem

Comment: In char inProgress[s];  s needs to be a constant value at compile time. E.g. inProgress[5] is fine. C++ language doesn't know about "dynamic resizable arrays". In this case use std::vector

Comment: No, it wouldn't, you need contexpr for that

Comment: You cannot in standard C++. Use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: Variable sized arrays are non-standard C++. Assuming you want a copy of the char data, replace `char inProgress[s];` with e.g.  `std::vector<char> inProgress(str.begin(), str.end());`

Comment: You can't allocate an array of anything *on stack* without knowing the size at compile time (which is not the case, since `str` is a function argument and can be anything). You can 1) allocate an array on the heap `char* a = new char[s]`, or better 2) use a standard container, that will do the allocation for you, e.g. `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc

Comment: @Lala5th No don't use, alloc, malloc or even new for resizable arrays. (The use of those is not recommended in the C++ core guidelines, https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). Really just use std::vector for this (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: C style arrays are quite low-level and not recommended on C++. Only fixed sizes are supported for local variables (except with proprietary compilers). Like `char inProgress[300];`. Even then the better alternative is `std::array<char, 300> inProgress;`. For a dynamic size use `std::vector<char> inProgress(s);` or if you want `std::unique_ptr<char[]> inProgress = std::make_unique<char[]>(s);`

Comment: Why do you need an array in the first place? Most of the time `std::string` is adequate for handling strings. `std::string inProgress = str;` should work just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **problem** is that in standard C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. This means that the following is incorrect in your program:

```
size_t s = str.length();
char inProgress[s]; //not standard C++ because s is not a constant expression
```

Better would be to use `std::vector` as shown below:

```
std::string AFunction(const std::string& str) {
    size_t s = str.length();

    std::vector<char> inProgress(s); //create vector of size `s`


    return std::string{};
}
```

Comment: `#include <vector>`, in this example the constructor used is `explicit vector( size_type count, const T& value = T(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());`