# C++ Allocating Memory Stack vs Heap

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a first year computer science major and have a question regarding memory allocation on the stack and heap.

```
int array[10];              // allocates memory on stack
int *ptr = new int[10];     // dynamically allocates memory on heap

// =========== code in question ============
int size;                   // I have intentionally left this variable uninitialized
cout << "enter size: ";
cin >> size;
int array_in_question[size];
// ======= end of code in question =========

for (int i{}; i < size; i++) {
    array_in_question[i] = i + 1;

    cout << array_in_question[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Our text book says that, "...you must specify the size of the array when you write the program..." referring to the line of code allocating memory on the stack. What is happening in the block of code labelled "code in question?" To me, it looks like "array_in_question" is being allocated on the stack although the size is known at compile time. How is this possible if the size of the array must be known at compile time?

I have search on stackoverflow and used search engines to look for an answer but have not found the information I was looking for.

Comment: [Old deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77865251/c-allocating-on-array-stack-or-heap)

Comment: `int array_in_question[size];` is not standard c++. Some compilers allow it as an extension. See [Expression does not evaluate to a constant error when declaring an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239263/expression-does-not-evaluate-to-a-constant/72239359#72239359)

Comment: it doesn't compile at all. C array size must be a compile-time value.

Comment: [C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

Comment: *How is this possible if the size of the array must be known at compile time?*  It's not possible in standard C++.  Turn on your compiler warnings.  Enable standard C++ on your compiler, such that it isn't using a VLA extension (like C has).

Comment: Also note that (regardless of what your university or your textbook is teaching you) in C++ it is more common to use `std::array<int,10>` for (fixed size/stack arrays) and `std::vector<int>` for dynamically allocated arrays. Somehow universities seem to forget to teach all improvements made to the language since C++11. C++ code hardly ever needs new/delete anymore (use std::make_unique or any of the containers like std::vector). Also unlearn to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: Check compiler warnings on your code here : https://godbolt.org/z/z9jdEWK83